# How to find the max of an array of array of doubles?

Tags: mysql, sql, hive

Data is in Hive, but also looking for sql recommendations.

I currently have a column that holds an array of an array of doubles.

Format looks like: `[[5.1],[7.0],[2.3],[3.5],[etc]]`

The inner array is always size of 1. I am trying to find the max of this and return a double where I can insert it back into another column.

I've tried performing two explodes, to remove both arrays, and then performing a MAX function, but the issue occurs when I have another similar column in the same format that I need to explode. Two explodes with lateral views creates an overlap of new rows.

Any other suggestions or UDF's to use?

Comment: In SQL could you create a View and use split function to explode the array? After that it should be a simple max on that view.

Comment: Using explodes should work. Can you post your SQL query?